# PHP/Mysql form with more checkboxes with some of the popup questions repeating

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Hi there i have a form (with specific id) that has checkboxes in it and when the checkbox is clicked, more questions (basicly a text field) will pop up. However some checkboxes have the same questions inside. Then I am saving the data to a mysql database. And i am displaying it afterwards. And the Question is: How to create some sort of switch statement or some algorithm that it would post in the current id and only to desired textfield.

Fo illustration:

```
0-100kg (Checkbox1)

- Which material? (textfield with name=material)

- Circle radius? (textfield with name=radius)

100-500kg (Checkbox2)

- Which material? (textfield with name=material)

- Circle radius? (textfield with name=radius)

500-1000kg (Checkbox3)

- Which material? (textfield with name=material)

- Circle radius? (textfield with name=radius)

- Roots? (textfield with name=roots)
```

Code:

Form:

```
<label class="collapse" for="100to500"><b>100 - 500kg</b></label>
<input id="100to500" type="checkbox" name="100to500">
<div><br>
Which material? <input type="text" name="material"/><br>
Circle radius? <input type="text" name="radius"/><br></div>

<label class="collapse" for="500to1000"><b>500 - 1000kg</b></label>
<input id="500to1000" type="checkbox" name="500to1000">
<div><br>
Which material? <input type="text" name="material"/><br>
Circle radius? <input type="text" name="radius"/><br>
Roots? <input type="text" name="roots"/><br></div>
```

PHP:

storing variables:

```
$material=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['material']);
$radius=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['radius']);
$roots=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['roots']);

$100to500 = isset($_POST['100to500']) ? $_POST['100to500'] : '0';
$500to1000= isset($_POST['500to1000']) ? $_POST['500to1000'] : '0';
```

I am trying to accopmlish that it would somehow save all the data into same id (database row) and save only the clicked on / filled data. I know it is a silly explanation but i am using PHP for 2 weeks only so im a complete noob :)

Thank you.

Comment: not a direct answer to your question, but seems like you'd be better off having the 2 question textfield + a selector for weight. Instead of weirdly having a set of duplicate questions under each weight category.

Comment: Ok i see someone downvoted, you could at least give me a lead if you think this post is unneccessary.

Comment: Yes it seems more logical to me as well :) thank you for your answer.

Comment: i edited my question, i now realize what i wanted to say

Comment: Please see that i want desired questions to pop up and as you can see 2 questions in checkbox2 and checkbox3 repeat.

Comment: Have you tried anything, I mean what have you coded so far? or do you expect us to code everything?..

Comment: You should also put up code that explains how the textboxes are created (or if they are there the whole time just invisible) and how your sql commands there look like

Comment: Of course i have, i have everything coded i will edit my post and post the code as well.

Comment: also on the part of code it is always important to know that is done via html/javascript and what is done via php  as approaches for help will be quite different if all is done via javascript or all is done via php and the page reloads on each selection (shouldn't be done that way but have seen it done that way in the past),.... so the more info you give on the code, the sql,... the easier it is to help (it is clear some things CAN't be said as they are companyinternal fo rthat its easier to change names of variables,... if these codeparts are necessary to showcase things),...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume you would not allow multiple section of weight categories? In that case use a select tag to limit user input.
secondly set you layout so that it looks like this

```
[dropdown list/ select]
- Which material? (textfield with name=material)
- Circle radius? (textfield with name=radius)
- Roots? (textfield with name=roots)
- Q4 e.t.c.
```

filter all your possible question for every weight categories and make a list of all UNIQUE questions.

then lastly, use javascript to show/hide each of the question according to the currently selected weight.
it is possible to use php to "dynamically" change the UI of a webpage, but it is kinda silly and is way less efficent than javascript.

The result form will be very easy to extract info from and won't give any possible duplicate textfield id/name

here's a mini sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Nn4zR/1/